# Top Values in a Query by Group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I know how to get the top values but am having trouble with something very simple.

I have a student table.  It has:

- name
- numberoflaps
- grade

I want the get a query or report that shows the top two kids with the most laps per grade.

Comment: What database (including version) are you using?  And what have you tried?

Comment: more information needed. using databases? what languages/platforms etc ...

Answer (score 5):

### Using MySQL:

---

MySQL doesn't have any ranking functionality, but it does allow for variable creation & updating:

```
SELECT x.grade,
       x.name,
       x.numberoflaps
  FROM (SELECT s.grade,
               s.name,
               s.numberoflaps,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @grade != s.grade THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1
               END AS rank,
               @grade := s.grade
          FROM STUDENTS s,
               (SELECT @rownum := 0, @grade := NULL) r
      ORDER BY s.grade, s.numberoflaps DESC) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 2
ORDER BY x.grade, x.rank
```

The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is important, otherwise the ranking won't be properly performed.

### Using Oracle 9i+/SQL Server 2005+:

---

Using a CTE:

```
WITH laps AS (
  SELECT s.grade, 
         s.name, 
         s.numberoflaps,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grade ORDER BY numberoflaps DESC) AS rank
    FROM STUDENTS s)
  SELECT l.grade, 
         l.name, 
         l.numberoflaps
    FROM laps l
   WHERE l.rank <= 2
ORDER BY l.grade, l.numberoflaps DESC
```

Non-CTE equivalent:

```
  SELECT l.grade, 
         l.name, 
         l.numberoflaps
    FROM (SELECT s.grade, 
                 s.name, 
                 s.numberoflaps,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grade ORDER BY numberoflaps DESC) AS rank
            FROM STUDENTS s) l
   WHERE l.rank <= 2
ORDER BY l.grade, l.numberoflaps DESC
```

### Caveat:

Oracle gained ranking functionality in 9i; for SQL Server it was 2005.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005+ version would look like this:

```
;WITH Laps_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        grade, name, numberoflaps,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY grade
            ORDER BY numberoflaps DESC
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM students
)
SELECT grade, name, numberoflaps
FROM Laps_CTE
WHERE RowNum <= 2
```

If that's not your dialect, please let us know what is.

Comment: I think you should have WHERE RowNum < 3 to return the top 2 rows

Comment: Sorry, I spent so long writing that comment Aaronaught had already fixed it!

Comment: @Martin Booth: Got to be quick around here :)