# Top results in each group using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Is there some good way of expressing queries returning top N results from each group in SqlAlchemy, or do I need to drop into raw SQL?

I mean queries like the one presented in [Top Values in a Query by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090804/top-values-in-a-query-by-group)
Since it requires manual counting in MySQL for example, it doesn't look like I could use any proper abstraction in the code, but maybe I'm missing something?

I'm looking for a solution that would be compatible with mysql, postgres, sqlite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273127/sqlalchemy-subquery-average-of-sums

Comment: @DerekLitz I don't think that's usable. He needs aggregate over all results from the group, I want top N from each group (related to ranking).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're answering your own question then.  Either return the information you need and drop into Python to do the top 5 filter, or write some interesting SQL or use a view that does it fore you.  Dropping into Python will at least give you a solution that's compatible with many DB's.  Returning unnecessary  information over the network is really the only incentive to jump through the SQL hoops, though.  Is it any issue in your case?  Not that writing three different queries for each (if the db even supports that type of stuff) would be any worse, just more code.